# Reset password in Laravel by typing email manually

Tags: php, laravel, reset, reset-password

How can I make this reset password work without using a token and adding an email manually to reset password.
Like for example in the image I want to change the password to the email I added which is edgar.lozoya@ujed.mx

How can I make this reset password work without using a token and adding an email manually to reset password.
Like for example in the image I want to change the password to the email I added which is edgar.lozoya@ujed.mx
[image: reset password form]

**This is the reset.blade.php:**
`@extends('layout.layout_reset')

@section('content')
<section class=" container section">

```
    <h1 class="h2 text-center">
        Restablecer contraseña
    </h1>
     @alert(['class' => 'alert--has-icon size-caption'])
    @endalert

    <div class="login-form ">
        <base-form action="{{ url('contrasena/restablecer') }}"
            inline-template
            v-cloak
        >
           <form method="POST" class="form-boxed"  action="{{ route('password.update') }}" >

                     @csrf

                    <text-field name="token" type="hidden" v-model="fields.token"   maxlength="60" placeholder="" ></text-field>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
                        <text-field name="email" type="email" v-model="fields.email" maxlength="60" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" placeholder="" initial=""></text-field>
                        <field-errors name="email"></field-errors> 
                        @error('email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
                            </span>
                         @enderror


                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="password">Nueva contraseña</label>
                        <text-field name="password" type="password" v-model="fields.password" maxlength="60" placeholder="" initial=""></text-field>
                        <field-errors name="password"></field-errors>
                        @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
                            </span>
                         @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="password_confirmation">Confirmar nueva contraseña</label>
                        <text-field name="password_confirmation" type="password" v-model="fields.password_confirmation" maxlength="60" placeholder="" initial=""></text-field>
                        <field-errors name="password_confirmation"></field-errors>
                        @error('password_confirmation')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
                            </span>
                         @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <form-button type="submit"  class="btn--success w-full">
                            Enviar
                        </form-button>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </base-form>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</section>
```

@endsection
`

This is the reset password controller code:
`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use App\User:
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reset Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
| and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
| explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
|
*/

```
use ResetsPasswords;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = 'admin';
protected function redirectTo(){
    if( Auth()->user()->role == 1){
        return route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    elseif( Auth()->user()->role == 2){
        return route('admin.dashboard');
    }
}

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}


public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
       ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
 );
}
```

}
`these are the routes in the web.php file`Route::post('passwords/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
Route::post('auth/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email'); `

I tried eliminating the token variables and requesting the email in the reset password controller

Comment: Without the token you'd have a system where anyone on earth who knows your email address could reset your password and take over your account.

Comment: Assuming this is a function to be used by an admin to set the password of a user, first find the user and then save the encrypted password - just basic CRUD function.  No need to use password reset flows